# Java 8 map with Map.get nullPointer Optimization

Tags: optimization, nullpointerexception, functional-programming, java-8

```
public class StartObject{
     private Something something;
     private Set<ObjectThatMatters> objectThatMattersSet;
}

public class Something{
     private Set<SomeObject> someObjecSet;
}

public class SomeObject {
     private AnotherObject anotherObjectSet;
}

public class AnotherObject{
     private Set<ObjectThatMatters> objectThatMattersSet;
}

public class ObjectThatMatters{
     private Long id;
}


private void someMethod(StartObject startObject) {
    Map<Long, ObjectThatMatters> objectThatMattersMap = StartObject.getSomething()
            .getSomeObject.stream()
            .map(getSomeObject::getAnotherObject)
            .flatMap(anotherObject-> anotherObject.getObjectThatMattersSet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(ObjectThatMatters -> ObjectThatMatters.getId(), Function.identity()));
   Set<ObjectThatMatters > dbObjectThatMatters = new HashSet<>();
   try {
        dbObjectThatMatters.addAll( tartObject.getObjectThatMatters().stream().map(objectThatMatters-> objectThatMattersMap .get(objectThatMatters.getId())).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        throw new someCustomException();
    }
 startObject.setObjectThatMattersSet(dbObjectThatMatters);
```

**Given** a StartObject that contains a set of ObjectThatMatters 
**And** a Something that contains the database structure already fetched filled with all valid ObjectThatMatters.
**When** I want to swap the StartObject set of ObjectThatMatters to the valid corresponding db objects that only exist in the scope of the Something
**Then** I compare the set of ObjectThatMatters on the StartObject 
**And** replace every one of them with the valid ObjectThatMatters inside the Something object 
**And** If some ObjectThatMatters doesn't have a valid ObjectThatMatters I throw a someCustomException 

**This someMethod seems pretty horrible, how can I make it more readable?** 
Already tried to change the try Catch to a optional but that doesn't actually help. 
Used a Map instead of a List with List.contains because of performance, was this a good idea? The total number of ObjectThatMatters will be usually 500. 
I'm not allowed to change the other classes structure and I'm only showing you the fields that affect this method not every field since they are extremely rich objects.

Comment: First of all, you should try to find a consistent naming policy. Almost nothing matches here. Besides, there is no point in collecting a stream into a `List`, only to perform `addAll` on a `Set` with it. You can collect into a `Set` in the first place. And using shorter lambda parameter names allows to recognize the actual operation in the code. The actual operation isn’t so complicated.

Comment: Holger this is not the actual code ... just an example. yep sorry wrote List and I should write Set you are right, fixed. Also the addAll is used since I need to go to the map to collect just the objects that matter for example the list of valid objects is 1500 objects and the list of objects that I want to change to the valid ones is 500 objects

Comment: You still have a property named `anotherObjectSet` which is not a `Set`. But anyway, you didn’t get the point. In your last operation, you are collecting the already filtered `ObjectThatMatters` instances int a `List` and perform `addAll` to a frashly create `HashSet`. There is no point in doing that. You can just collect into a `Set`, there is no semantic difference, it’s only shorter, more readable and more efficient.

Comment: Besides, there is no code that would throw a `NullPointerException` for a non-matching id. The code would simply collect a `null` into the result. That demonstrates, what a bad idea it is to rely on such a behavior…

Comment: Holger, thank you very much I thought that map.get returns exception instead of null, so now I'm .filter(Objects::nonNull) clearing the nulls, and comparing the size of the lists to know if any null was returned and cleared, it looks much better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need a mapping step at all. The first operation, which produces a `Map`, can be used to produce the desired `Set` in the first place. Since there might be more objects than you are interested in, you may perform a filter operation.

So first, collect the IDs of the desired objects into a set, then collect the corresponding db objects, filtering by the `Set` of IDs. You can verify whether all IDs have been found, by comparing the resulting `Set`’s size with the ID `Set`’s size.

```
private void someMethod(StartObject startObject) {
    Set<Long> id = startObject.getObjectThatMatters().stream()
        .map(ObjectThatMatters::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet());

    HashSet<ObjectThatMatters> objectThatMattersSet =
        startObject.getSomething().getSomeObject().stream()
            .flatMap(so -> so.getAnotherObject().getObjectThatMattersSet().stream())
            .filter(obj -> id.contains(obj.getId()))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

    if(objectThatMattersSet.size() != id.size())
        throw new SomeCustomException();

    startObject.setObjectThatMattersSet(objectThatMattersSet);
}
```

This code produces a `HashSet`; if this is not a requirement, you can just use `Collectors.toSet()` to get an arbitrary `Set` implementation.

It’s even easy to find out which IDs were missing:

```
private void someMethod(StartObject startObject) {
    Set<Long> id = startObject.getObjectThatMatters().stream()
        .map(ObjectThatMatters::getId)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));// ensure mutable Set

    HashSet<ObjectThatMatters> objectThatMattersSet =
        startObject.getSomething().getSomeObject().stream()
            .flatMap(so -> so.getAnotherObject().getObjectThatMattersSet().stream())
            .filter(obj -> id.contains(obj.getId()))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));

    if(objectThatMattersSet.size() != id.size()) {
        objectThatMattersSet.stream().map(ObjectThatMatters::getId).forEach(id::remove);
        throw new SomeCustomException("The following IDs were not found: "+id);
    }

    startObject.setObjectThatMattersSet(objectThatMattersSet);
}
```

Comment: id.contains(obj.getId() is a really bad solution, since with 500 values it generates 250 000 iterations, the more it grows the worst it gets but that .filter(obj -> id.contains(obj.getId())) and if(objectThatMattersSet.size() != id.size()) { was just genius. Huge thanks I'm having big problems changing my way of thinking into functional programming and you just made my day

Comment: `id.contains` does not perform an iteration, if `id` is a `Set`, i.e. for a `HashSet`, it performs an `O(1)` hash lookup. In your original code, you’re performing only 500 lookups when building the `Set`, but already performed *totalNumber* lookups when building the `Map`. So in either case, you’re performing 500 + *totalNumber* lookups, only in different order.